# I want to add a progress bar in j2me application

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I want to add a progress bar in j2me application that shows the busy process.

I am doing this using alert adding gauge as indicator but it disappears on button click.

Comment: Hey here is good example for [ProgressAlert](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/alerts20/index.html) , this will help you.

Comment: or optionally you can use canvas also.

Comment: show the snippet of the code you're having problems with

Comment: I Guess the link for ProgressAlert is dead please update it @Mister Sajid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to go with LCDUI Alert or LWUIT you can use Canvas. I have shared a very simple sample at http://smallandadaptive.blogspot.com.br/2009/09/adding-simple-progress-bar.html Full text below:

A progress bar is a visual representation of a Real Number between zero and one or a percentage between 0% and 100%.

Below is a method for drawing a simple progress bar:

```
    /**
     * @param g Graphics
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @param w width
     * @param h height
     * @param p part between zero and total
     * @param t total
     */
    void fillProgressBar (Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h, int p, int t) {
      g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
      // p will receive the pixel width of the proportion: part / total
      p = (p * w) / t;
      g.fillRect(x, y, p, h);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

from LWUIT we can show progress in 2 ways

1) Displaying some gif image in a dialog and dont dispose dialogue until we get complete response from server / dispose it after complete processing

2) From LWUIT 1.5 we have component called Slider and Sliderfull , we can use that componet to show some progress until processing is done.

for further info please go through this blog [Slider](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010/07/sliding-it-back-to-my-first-post.html?spref=bl)